# Eclipse problem occurred at opening xml file

Tags: xml, eclipse, macos, m2e

for some reasons I can't open plain xml files anymore. I did a few tests and even with a fresh, untouched copy of eclipse (64bit cocoa), I can't open xml files. What I did is, created a new java project, created a new xml file. The only thing I get is following message:

An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Could not initialize class org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml.PomContentAssistProcessor

Any ideas what the reason might be?

update:

I had a closer look at the error log, displaying following:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml.PomContentAssistProcessor
```

Somehow dependencies are missing, but I don't know how to solve it. I tried to re-install m2e, but it just told me that it is already installed and will only show up in installed applications.

Here's the full stacktrace, maybe somebody has an advice what to do next.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml.PomContentAssistProcessor
    at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml.PomStructuredTextViewConfiguration.getContentAssistProcessors(PomStructuredTextViewConfiguration.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextViewerConfiguration.getContentAssistant(StructuredTextViewerConfiguration.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.StructuredTextViewer.configure(StructuredTextViewer.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractTextEditor.java:3407)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.createPartControl(StatusTextEditor.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.createPartControl(StructuredTextEditor.java:1508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLMultiPageEditorPart.addSourcePage(XMLMultiPageEditorPart.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLMultiPageEditorPart.createPages(XMLMultiPageEditorPart.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.findEditor(EditorManager.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2887)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2850)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2842)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2789)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2773)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2764)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1152)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4125)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1457)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1480)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1270)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3971)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem with indigo, just opened the original downloaded zip and overwritten all the jar files in plugins directory that start with `org.eclipse.m2e.*` and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

I got this worked by starting my Eclipse(Kepler) with a -clean parameter..

```
"d:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -clean"
```

When I tried this, eclipse took more time than usual to comeup, as it will be cleaning and reloading plug-ins.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but this post was back in 2011 and well and Vitali Bichov's comment worked out ;)

Answer (score 2):

Similar problem when attempting to open XML or Java files:
`org/eclipse/wst/xml/ui/internal/tabletree/XMLMultiPageEditorPart`
Could not open xml or java files.

Eclipse Kepler 4.3.  IDE got killed by a winturds system restart.
Subsequently, started IDE, error

My clever solution: Exit IDE through File:Exit and restart the IDE.  This has happened before.

Your mileage may vary.

Comment: its quite a while ago but a clean re-install fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If a fresh copy doesn't work this means the workspace or project metadata is corrupted. Try creating a new workspace.

The problem looks related to m2eclipse - eclipse is trying to load the pom-editor but fails. You can try installing/updating m2eclipse as well.

Comment: somehow I can't resolve it. Seems that I'm on the latest updates, eclipse Build id: 20110615-0604 and m2e 1.0.0.20110607-2117.

Comment: it's not possible for a fresh eclipse + fresh workspace not to work. You are having something cached somewhere

Comment: I deleted all files, including ~/Library/Caches/org.eclipse.. and within my home directory .eclipse_keyring, Then I downloaded a fresh copy, created a brand new workspace, but the message is the same. After that I tried to restart eclipse with -clean, no results. Are there any other ideas left?

Comment: You've seen this with a fresh copy of Eclipse *without* m2eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with luna. Regenerate the library plug-in dependencies worked for me.